# How to replace a number with another one?

Tags: command-line

I want to replace a number with another number which is stored in a variable. How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace in what? Using what?

Comment: Use parameter expansion, explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)!

Comment: Please add a little more detail: What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warnings or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety by editing your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In the second line of my file there is a number (25). I need it to be replaced by another number stored in a variable. I haven't used any code for that. I have been searching the web to find something.